# Changing current culture

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need to change the current culture for a script and nothing I tried works.

I've tried using the `Set-Culture` cmdlet.

I've trued setting `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx

Comment: Yes, it works - as expected. I'm literal going crazy with this. I had seen that post and tried it and it failed. Although at this point I'm not so sure of that.